# OpenLayers adding/removing layer when checkbox is changed

Tags: javascript, openlayers, jquery

I am trying to add and remove `layers2` layer when checkbox is changed. How can I do it with jquery?

Following my way  i get: `Uncaught ReferenceError: layers is not defined`

```
     var wmsLayer2 = new ol.layer.Image({
          source: wmsSource2
        });

        $("#Buildings_chkbx").change(function(){
   var bool = !bool;
    if(bool)
          layers.push(wmsLayer2);
    else
    //remove layer...
        });


        var map = new ol.Map({
          target: 'map',
          layers: [baseLayer, wmsLayer],
          view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([33.33386, 35.14710]),
            zoom: 14
          })
        });
```

Comment: Yes, it's the same. Following this logic is giving me `Uncaught ReferenceError: layers is not defined`

Comment: well, what **is** `layers`? Where do you define it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i managed to make it work:

```
 var wmsLayer2 = new ol.layer.Image({
      source: wmsSource2
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [baseLayer, wmsLayer], 
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([33.33386, 35.14710]),
        zoom: 14
      })
    });

    $("#Buildings_chkbx").change(function (){
      if ($("#Buildings_chkbx").is(':checked'))
        map.addLayer(wmsLayer2);
      else
        map.removeLayer(wmsLayer2);
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you create your `map`, it is static, which means it will allways have the same layers. In particular only because you change the array, that was used to populate the `map`, does not mean the `map` itself will reflect those changes. Doing anything to `layers` (which I assume is defined somewhere above as an array or similar) won´t do anything to the `map`.

You can however call `addLayer` and `removeLayer` on the map to dynamically add remove a layer once the map was created.

```
var wmsLayer2 = new ol.layer.Image({
  source: wmsSource2
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [baseLayer, wmsLayer], // probably you want wmsLayer2 here, don´t you?
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([33.33386, 35.14710]),
    zoom: 14
  })
});

$("#Buildings_chkbx").change(function(){
  bool = !bool;
  if(bool)
    map.addLayer(wmsLayer2);
  else
    map.removeLayer(wmsLayer2);
});
```

Comment: It works on the first click but later on it gives me the following error message: `Assertion failed. See https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/doc/errors/#58 for details.`

Comment: bool always returns true that's why. Also you need to do `var bool = !bool;`

Comment: @csandreas1 If you´d write `var bool = !bool!` I´d expect that to allways evaluate o `true`. You would need the variable defined **outside** the change-event-handler.

Comment: use this instead: `if($(this).is(':checked') ) //add layer else ....`

Comment: @csandreas1 Good idea, however I would use `if($(this).checked)` to determine the check-state of your checkbox.